# group archive in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to create an archive list like this:

- 2016

  - July 2016

    - testing 5 of 16
    - testing 4 of 16
    - testing 3 of 16
    - testing 2 of 16
  - February 2016

    - testing 1 of 16
- 2015

  - November 2015

    - testing 1 of 15

but it is showing like this:

- 2016

  - July 2016

    - testing 5 of 16
    - testing 4 of 16
    - testing 3 of 16
    - testing 2 of 16
  - February 2016

    - testing 1 of 16
  - November 2015

    - testing 1 of 15
- 2016

  - July 2016

    - testing 5 of 16
    - testing 4 of 16
    - testing 3 of 16
    - testing 2 of 16
  - February 2016

    - testing 1 of 16
  - November 2015

    - testing 1 of 15
- 2015

  - July 2016

    - testing 5 of 16
    - testing 4 of 16
    - testing 3 of 16
    - testing 2 of 16
  - February 2016

    - testing 1 of 16
  - November 2015

    - testing 1 of 15

This is my source code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blogs ORDER BY date DESC";
$resultSet = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultSet)){
$newsArray = array();

echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;                                           

while ($newsResult = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)){ 
    $newDate =  $newsResult['date'] ;   
    $timePeriod = date('F  Y ',strtotime($newDate));
    $timePeriodY = date('Y',strtotime($timePeriod));
    $timePeriodM = date('F',strtotime($timePeriod));                                          

    /*if (!isset($newsArray[$timePeriod])){
          $newsArray[$timePeriod] = array();
    }*/
    $newsArray[$timePeriod][] = $newsResult;                                      
}                                         

//by year
foreach ($newsArray as $timePeriod => $newsItems){
    $timePeriodY = date('Y',strtotime($timePeriod));
    echo '<li><strong>' . $timePeriodY . '</strong>' . PHP_EOL;  
    echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;

    //by month
    foreach ($newsArray as $timePeriod => $newsItems){
        echo '<li><strong>' . $timePeriod . '</strong>' . PHP_EOL;  
        echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;                                

        //news items
        foreach ($newsItems as $item){
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="'.$wwwUrl.'press-releases/'.$item["id"].'/'.$item["titlename"].'.php">'.$item["titlename"].'</a>';
            echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
        }     

        //end by month
        echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
        echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;                   
    }

    //end by year
    echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;                   
}

echo '<li>&nbsp;</li>' . PHP_EOL;   
echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
} else {
echo 'No Blog Found';
}
```

Please help me with this and thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I may provide some constructive feedback, your example could have been made more compact. I bet a lot of people just clicked away when they had to use a scrollbar to reach the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're "grouping" by "F Y" when you should be "grouping" by "Y" and then "F Y"

For example :

```
$newsArray[$timePeriod][] =  $newsResult;
```

Should be something like

```
$newsArray[$timePeriodY][timePeriod][]=  $newsResult;
```

Your code will then become:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blogs ORDER BY date DESC";
$resultSet = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultSet)){
$newsArray = array();

echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;                                           

while ($newsResult = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)){ 
    $newDate =  $newsResult['date'] ;   
    $timePeriod = date('F  Y ',strtotime($newDate));
    $timePeriodY = date('Y',strtotime($timePeriod));
    $timePeriodM = date('F',strtotime($timePeriod));                                          


    $newsArray[$timePeriodY][$timePeriod][] = $newsResult;                                      
}                                         

//by year
foreach ($newsArray as $timePeriodY => $newsItems){
    echo '<li><strong>' . $timePeriodY . '</strong>' . PHP_EOL;  
    echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;

    //by month
    foreach ($newsItems as $timePeriod => $items){
        echo '<li><strong>' . $timePeriod . '</strong>' . PHP_EOL;  
        echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;                                

        //news items
        foreach ($items as $item){
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="'.$wwwUrl.'press-releases/'.$item["id"].'/'.$item["titlename"].'.php">'.$item["titlename"].'</a>';
            echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
        }     

        //end by month
        echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
        echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;                   
    }

    //end by year
    echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
    echo '</li>' . PHP_EOL;                   
}

echo '<li>&nbsp;</li>' . PHP_EOL;   
echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL; 
} else {
echo 'No Blog Found';
}
```